# Active admin input field with locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, activeadmin, globalize3, globalize

I have built **multi-language** application.But at this point I see lot of trouble to edit my translations through **ActiveAdmin** interface. I want to be able add/edit translations through this interface. Because using seeds.rb is not an option for user.

Idea is to have 2 text fields when editing/creating product, where in the first one I could write product description in my native language and in second description in english. I don't to create new column for products table. I wan't to use built in **Globalize3** structure.

Where is other table like `category_translations`.

If I try like this:

```
form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
  f.inputs "Content" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :condition, :collection => @condition,:hint=>"Select condition"
    f.input :sub_desc, :input_html => { :class => "tinymce" }
    f.input :description, :input_html => { :class => "tinymce" },:locale=>'en'
    f.input :description, :input_html => { :class => "tinymce" },:locale=>'lv'  
    f.input :technical_data, :input_html => {:class=>"tinymce" }
    f.input :intro_text
    f.input :category, :collection => @category
    f.input :slug
    f.input :manufacturer, :collection => @manufacturer,:hint=>"Choose manufacturer"
  end
  f.inputs "Image" do 
  f.input :photo, :as => :file, :hint=>"Select image to upload. Allowed file formats *jpg *png, Soft signs not Allowed"
     #form :partial => "form"
  end
  f.actions
  end
```

Where I am trying to set locale variable to input, but this gives me no errors at all.
Somebody had similar problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the activeadmin-globalize gem. It gives you a nice interface to handle fields that has translations.

Gem for Globalize3: https://rubygems.org/gems/activeadmin-globalize3

I have not tested this version, because we are using Globalize in our project with the activeadmin-globalize taken from: https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize.

There is a pull request that lowers the dependency of activeadmin-globalize so it can be used in a Rails 3.2 app: https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize/pull/38

Comment: What is the difference between those two ?

Comment: Globalize3 is deprecated. Globalize is the actual branch. activeadmin-globalize uses the newer one.

Comment: There is a pull request that makes activeadmin-globalize available under Rails 3. You should check it: https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize/pull/38